# in Visual Studio code, how to extend the maximum line width

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

No matter what I did, I can't set the line to be bigger than 80 characters. I went in settings and set all to 160, but to no avail. I have prettier, but I don't know how to see its config file. Do you know how to enlarge the maximum line length? I am developing typescript (angular to be precise).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VSCode does *soft* wrapping (changing how long lines are *displayed*).

Prettier does *hard* wrapping (adding or removing newlines in the text content to try to get a certain length).

VSCode has chosen to leave hard wrapping to extensions but none of the ones I've tried work.

Prettier is deliberately not configurable, and its most stupid rule *joins* short lines into longer ones (which is why I prefer Eslint).

Comment: Now how to stop this from happening using Prettier

Comment: Actually, you can ....But ...not as in general ... You should tweek the particular programming's settings

Comment: Prettier has a property called 'printWidth'. Set this to your desired column number for autowrapping in settings.json. "prettier.printWidth": 140

Answer (score 81):

To completely disable the wrapping:

> Settings > Editor: Word Wrap > Off

To set the wrapping to the 160th column:

> Settings > Editor: Word Wrap > wordWrapColumn
>
> Settings > Editor: Word Wrap Column > 160

Or add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 160
```

You can open the settings file by pressing F1 and typing `settings.json`.

Comment: typing my name you mean? Vladimir?

Comment: The name - of the file - `settings.json`

Comment: The settings are in the gear icon not the menu. 'Editor' should be 'Text Editor'

Comment: My word wrap option is set to off but it's still capping it at 80 (default value). I set it to 500 and problem is gone, but... not ideal.

Comment: Wrapping is okay, but is there any way to end automatically the line, and add a continuation in the code in the next line, when typing in? That way, the code will be (I'm not sure how to explain it) trimmed at the same column number, and continued on the following. This is what I mean: https://gist.github.com/carloswm85/2c156065c171003c2fd8ae2f2b28ee1a

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Tailwind classes were off to Narnia before adding this. As a note for others, you can set the settings for VSCode on a project basis by adding `.vscode/settings.json` to your root directory.

Comment: If anyone is using Prettier extension,  search for `printwidth` in Settings and set the value. It worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

the latest version of visual studio code (or codium) seems to handle multiple wrap lines.

in `settings.json` for example:

```json
"editor.rulers": [100, 120, 140]
```

Answer (score 10):

As of 2022 (or probably earlier), you can use "prettier.printWidth: 80" in your settings.json (Change value according to preferences).
Follow [link](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) for more details.
Hope this helped

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to stop Prettier wrapping lines.  In particular, you probably don't want it to join short lines together but it treats `printWidth` as a target length and will join lines to try to hit that target.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `.prettierrc` file in your project, specify the line length that the printer will wrap on by including the `printWidth` option with a value of your choice:

```json
"printWidth": 120 // default is 80
```

Consider reading [this](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) reference before changing this option.

Answer (score 4):

with Prettier, note that one can modify `printWidth` without a `.prettierrc` file. Simply navigate to `Settings (UI) -> Prettier: Print Width`, and the column width value can be changed directly from there. This is what fixed it for me. :)

Answer (score 4):

I use Dart language with VSCode. I tried to set the line length to 100 at various places through the File/preferences/settings dialog, but all of them failed. Finally this is what worked: I edited the settings.json file and adjusted the following entries:

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        100
    ],
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
"prettier.printWidth": 100,
"dart.lineLength": 100,
"editor.rulers": [
    100
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It was driving me crazy until I discovered it was an extension. In my case HTML extension, with the Wrap Line Length setting.

You can find it in the settings.json file as

```
html.format.wrapLineLength
```

To find this out, I inputted text to find the maximun allowed for one line (120 in my case), then I searched that value in my settings file.

Regards.

Comment: that's the problem, too many extensions do the same thing, and they override each other in unpredictable manner. So you don't know where to start looking for a problem....it's so fuçꝁing annoying.