# is it possible to increase the code area in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want more code to fit into the line, but I'm limited to this strip.
Is it possible to increase the code area in vscode?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you type beyond that line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Visual Studio code, how to extend the maximum line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060373/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-extend-the-maximum-line-width)

Comment: no, it's doesn't work. @Code-Apprentice I added second pic to explain

Comment: What device/os are you on?

Comment: @Goman60 win10 enterprise

Comment: Sorry, idk then. I have done it on Mac.

Comment: @Goman60 What doesn't work? Did you disable line wrap like the link I gave explains?

Comment: All I was saying is that I don't know my way around Windows OS, so I am not fit to give advice.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I did it,and it still doesn't work

Comment: @srzh What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: the code still wraps to the next line after the vertical line

Answer (score 0):

strip is removed in settings.json:

```
"[dart]" : {

"editor.rulers": []
}
```

line break is removed by disabling:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

or disable completely formatter:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": null
}
```