# How to increase working space in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Coming from this [picture](https://ibb.co/R6P4wxV), it seems that I still have more space to the right. How can I disable line break? I searched in the settings but "word wrap disable" didn't help

Solution: settings / Dart: Line length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Visual Studio code, how to extend the maximum line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060373/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-extend-the-maximum-line-width)

Comment: That link didn't help. Seems that I need to move "horizontal grey line" a little bit right to increase working space. It's a bit weird since if I have wide screen, why I should be seized by 30% width of my monitor?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ggRYktF
https://ibb.co/QFshMqS

Amount is changed, vscode restarted. Still no effect.

Comment: Do your lines actually wrap at that grey line?  That line is probably just a `ruler` - which can be disabled and has no effect on line wrapping - it is just a guide.

Comment: Yes, after I managed to get rid of that grey ruler, I found out that I still have limitation on code line length. 

So to extend the size of code line, one needs to open "Settings" and then search for "Line settings". By default it's 80 symbols

Comment: Btw, what do I need ruler for? How can it improve coding?