# When using gopls, how to increase the length at which the line is wrapped?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

How do I increase the length of a line at which `gopls` will split function into multiple lines? I've disabled go language server and it stopped splitting the line so `gopls` is the cause and I'm hoping there is setting somewhere to change the default.

For example this code:

```golang
func A() { return /* this code will wrap if you paste this into vs code <...........................> */ }

func B() { return /* this code will not wrap if you paste this into vs code <......................> */ }
```

will get split like this:

```golang
func A() {
    return /* this code will wrap if you paste this into vs code <...........................> */
}

func B() { return /* this code will not wrap if you paste this into vs code <......................> */ }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Visual Studio code, how to extend the maximum line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060373/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-extend-the-maximum-line-width)

Comment: which one of gofmt, goimports, goreturns, and gofumpt are you using? What's the value of your `go.formatTool` setting? cc @JimWright no.

Comment: @JimWright it does not unfortunately

Comment: @starball the value of go.formatTool is default and I have language server (gopls) enabled which the docs suggest it will use to format..

Answer (score -1):

I don't do Go development, so I might be wrong, but looking at the gopls docs, the only formatting settings are `local` and `gofumpt`, and [`go.formatFlags`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/settings#goformatflags) and [`go.formatTool`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/settings#goformattool). And `go.formatFlags` is only relevant when not using the language server for formatting.

- https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/settings.md#formatting
- https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/master:gopls/doc/settings.md
- https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/settings

So I think you'd need to use some other formatting option (`go.formatTool`) to have more control over how formatting works.

Though again, I'm no Go dev, so take what I say with a grain of salt. I'd be happy to be wrong.