Does anybody know how to avoid this weird format in VS Code?

I made an HTML file and when I saved it, the formatting happens, but it adds those white spaces and line jumps for whatever reason.
I uninstalled VS Code and all the extensions that I had to have a kinda fresh start because this formatting issue was happening.
I reinstalled VS Code; installed just Prettier again; apply it on a HTML file and it happens again, some whitespace and line jump that has no sense at all to me.

Not certain, but possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060373/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-extend-the-maximum-line-width (answers contain a mix of VSCode and Prettier based responses)

it looks like the previous line is a word wrap

It would be helpful if you posted the html text as text as well so someone could copy/paste it to see if they can replicate the issue easily.
